# Get Element id Inside Container for dynamically added div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this function to get the other next div id inside the div element.

html

```
<div id="div1" >
    <input type="text" id="edit1" />
    <input type="text" id="edit2" />
    <input type="text" id="edit3" />
</div>
```

js

```
function GetElementInsideContainer(containerID, childID) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(childID);
    var parent = elm ? elm.parentNode : {};
    return (parent.id && parent.id === containerID) ? elm : {};
}

var e = GetElementInsideContainer("div1", "edit1");
alert(e.id); // it alerts "edit2"
```

However, it doesnt work (alerts [object] [object]) when the divs have been added dynamically. What is the correct way to make it also work for dynamically added content ?

Comment: So it seems that you have multiple elements with the same `editX` ids. Right. If so, that would be the problem. You shouldn't need to verify that `edit1` for example is inside `div1`, because there can only be one `edit1` on the page, unless you're trying to exclude it when it happens to not be in `div1`.

Comment: But it doesnt mean that they have same ids. Just similar.

Comment: Then you need to provide a full demonstration of the issue instead of just a fragment of the problem.

Comment: Just tested your code snippet and for me it returns "edit1". Maybe you have your page cached?